# Google protocol buffers-Sending a message form C# client to a java Server

Tags: c#, java, stream, network-programming, protocol-buffers

The Client sends a 1481 bytes array.
The server can read all the 1481 bytes message without any problems but by parsing the given messsage from the received binary array i get this **exeption**:

`com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).`

The binary data is the same. I checked that I am using the right version of the proto files. I am a bit at a loss tbh. Any help appreciated.

**Code**

`byte [] data= IOUtils.toByteArray(br1, "ASCII");
System.out.println("SIZE:" + data.length);

AddressBook adb1 = AddressBook.parseFrom(data);         System.out.println("Server: Addressbook:" + adb1.getPersonCount());         System.out.println("Server: Addressbook:" + adb1.getPerson(0).getName());`

**Question:**

I need to find a way to correctly parse the received Adressbook msg from the read 1481 bytes arry.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean 1481 bytes, not bits, right? When you say "the binary data is the same" - the same as what? It's hard to follow what's actually going on here.

Comment: i mean the length of byteArray is 1481.

Comment: Right. It's important to know the difference between bytes and bits, and use the right term. The rest of the question is still vague.

Comment: The received binary data is the same as the sent data

Comment: the Problem allthough the received binary data is the same as the sent data i get this Exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).

Comment: How have you validated that, and have you tried eliminating the network part entirely? I suggest you create a file instead, and try reading that file from both Java and C# code.

Comment: for (int i =0; i <data.length; i++ )
{
System.out.print(data[i]);
}

Comment: no i dont use a file only for loop to compare the received data with the send byte array

Comment: I was suggesting that you *should* use a file - but now that you've posted the code (badly formatted, but...), it seems pretty clear what's wrong - see my answer.

Comment: Now it works I had mistakes by [Serializing][1] and [Sending][2] the Protocol Buffers Message


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165690/serializing-and-sending-a-protocol-buffers-message
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186848/streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-when-reading-objectinputstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works I had same mistake by [Serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165690/serializing-and-sending-a-protocol-buffers-message/13190701#13190701) and [Sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186848/streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-when-reading-objectinputstream) the Protocol Buffers Message

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
br1 = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
```

That's trying to treat opaque binary data as *text*. It's not text, it's binary data. So when you convert that `Reader` into a byte array, you've lost a load of the original data - no wonder it's an invalid protocol buffer.

Just use:

```
AddressBook adb1 = AddressBook.parseFrom(s.getInputStream());
```

and avoid the lossy text conversion. That's assuming you haven't got something equally broken on the C# side, of course.

If you *must* go via text, you should use base64 encoding on both sides.

Comment: why i lost a load of the original data if i convert that Reader into a byte arry? I tried your proposal but i get the same **exception** :  `com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)`

Comment: How could i use the base64 encoding on both sides? Thanks!

Comment: @Kaiser4you: No, you **shouldn't use a Reader at all**. That's the whole point. Readers are about *text* data. A protocol buffer message is *binary* data. Just don't do it! You should only resort to base64 if you *absolutely have to use text* - which is unlikely.

Comment: Thanks! 
Ok which I/O steam it is better to use in this case: BuffredInputStream or DataInputStream or ObjectInputStream?

Comment: @Kaiser4you: Unless you're *using* any of the features provided by `DataInputStream` or `ObjectInputStream`, don't use them. You may not even need to use `BufferedInputStream`, as IIRC the Protobuf implementation performs buffering. Just use `s.getInputStream()`, as per my answer.

Comment: I need the features of ObjectInputStream could I use it?

Comment: @Kaiser4you: I fail to see *how* you could use that, given that you're going to ask Protocol Buffers to parse the stream... what would you want to use it for?

Comment: When i use it i get this exception: invalid stream header: 0A290A08

Comment: @Kaiser4you: You haven't answered the previous question, and now you've given an error without any clue about where it's being thrown from. I'm afraid it's *very* hard to help you.

Comment: But when i use a java client it works....I need the method objectInputStream.readByte();

Comment: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A290A08

Comment: @Kaiser4you: Still not nearly enough information (what's the stack trace?), and you've never explained why you would need to call `readByte()` when you should be just passing the stream to `AddressBook.parseFrom`. Sorry, I don't have time to get information from you one tiny piece at a time.